# Ruby Variables wont add or subtract

Tags: ruby, variables, counting

I'm trying to add numbers to a variable then display the variable, but the variable just stays the same :( Here's the code...

```
cash = 50  
puts "You have #{cash} dollars"
sleep (2)
cash + 5
puts "You have #{cash} dollars"
```

it just shows up as 50 still. can someone help ?

Comment: May I suggest that you'd be doing yourself a favor and save yourself a lot of grief if you would take half a day and read the intro chapters of one of the many fine books out there?

Answer (score 2):

Write it as `cash = cash + 5`, you will get the desired output.`cash + 5` created new `Fixnum` instance `55`, but you didn't assign back the reference of the object `55` to the local variable `cash`. Look below :

```
cash = 50  
puts "You have #{cash} dollars"
sleep(2) # or you can write as sleep 2
cash = cash + 5
puts "You have #{cash} dollars"
# >> You have 50 dollars
# >> You have 55 dollars
```

Now if you don't want `cash = cash + 5`, do as below :

```
cash = 50  
puts "You have #{cash} dollars"
sleep(2) # or you can write as sleep 2
puts "You have #{cash+5} dollars"
# >> You have 50 dollars
# >> You have 55 dollars
```

Comment: Thanks :) Now that you say that, I remember seeing it put like that before

Comment: Don't put a space between method name and opening parenthesis. Because Matz said so.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks sir... I didn't notice that..Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

By itself, `cash + 5` only *outputs* the evaluation – in your case, you want to *assign* the output to `cash`:

```
cash = 50                       # Declare the `cash` variable
#=> 50 

puts "You have #{cash} dollars" # Print the value of `cash`
#=> You have 50 dollars

cash + 5                        # Print the value of (`cash` + 5) WITHOUT assigning it
#=> 55

puts "You have #{cash} dollars" # Print the value of `cash`
#=> You have 50 dollars

cash = cash + 5                 # Assign the returned value of (`cash` + 5) to `cash`
#=> 55

puts "You have #{cash} dollars" # Print the value of `cash`
#=> You have 55 dollars
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cash = 50  
puts "You have #{cash} dollars"
sleep (2)
cash + 5   # this just returns 55 in ruby. For example you could have newVar = cash + 5 , newVar would equal 55 but cash still would equal 50
puts "You have #{cash} dollars"
```

To get your desired amount do the following.
The most common way to add to the variable each time is like this

```
cash += 5
```

This is shorthand for

```
cash = cash + 5
```

Comment: `//` is not used in Ruby as a comment indicator syntax. Use `#`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cash + 5
```

In the code above you sum 5 to cash, but the result is discarded. In fact, there is no assignment on the right.

```
cash = cash + 5
```

will produce the desired result. In this case, you can also use the shortand

```
cash += 5
```